# Using pre-trained word embedding and real value

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, word-embedding

I have created a model of NER with Keras with pre-trained word embedding.

I would like to add to my model a  tag with the long of the string.

I don't find the way to do it.

```
def model_keras(windows, embedding_w):
    context_columns = []
    for i in range(windows):
         context_columns = Sequential()
         context_columns.add(Embedding(....weights = [embedding_w],trainable=False)
         context_columns += [context_columns]
    ContextWindows = Merge(context_columns, mode='concat')
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ContextWindows)
    model.add(SimpleRNN...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, ideally, I would like to have a ContextWindows like that :

```
 [embeddingWord1 valueCentralWord (if number else 0)  isNumberCentralWord(0/1)   isintvaleurCentralWord(0/1) embeddingWord2]
```

For the moment, I have:

```
 [embeddingWord1 embeddingCentralWord embeddingWord2]
```